# Angular2 how to get errors message of form?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I want to get errors message in function of component instead show them in template:

```
<p [hidden]="!name.control.errors.required" *ngIf="name?.control?.errors?.required">name is required</p>
```

How to get errors message of form in function of Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the control associated to the input, you can do the same thing:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <form>
      <input [ngFormControl]="control"/>
    </form>
    <div (click)="showError()">Show error</div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.control = new Control('', Validators.required);
  }

  showError() {
    if (this.control.errors.required) {
      // Have the required error
    }
  }
}
```